# vue2 xlsx not working for statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, xlsx

npm i xlsx

---

```
 methods: {   
          async excelDown1() {
              const xlsx = require("xlsx");
        
              const book = xlsx.utils.book_new();
        
           
              const dataByAoa = await this.getFruitDataByAoa1();
        
        
              const worksheetByAoa = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(dataByAoa);
        
              xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(book, worksheetByAoa, "DailyInspection");
        
        
              xlsx.writeFile(book, "DailyInspection.xlsx");
            },
            getFruitDataByAoa1() {
              let arr = [];
              arr.push([
                "Equipmentcode",
                 "InspectionDay",
                 "checklist",
                 "Checkcontent",
                 "Checkresults",
                 "Checker",
                 "note",
              ]);
              for (let index = 0; index < this.daydatas.length + 1; index++) {
                arr.push([
                  this.daydatas[index].Machinecd,
                  this.daydatas[index].Checkdt,
                  this.daydatas[index].CheckItem,
                  this.daydatas[index].CheckPart,
                  this.daydatas[index].CheckResult,
                  this.daydatas[index].CheckUser,
                  this.daydatas[index].Remark,
                ]);
                console.log("go");
              }
              console.log("gogo");
        
              return arr;
            },
    }
```

---

The for statement does not return. Only 'gogo' is printed. Is it wrong to add an excel table like this? xlsx was used.

If you put 0 instead of 'index', one line will be printed.
Any code will not work if you put it inside a for statement. Why is the for statement not working?

Comment: Please provide the code that instantiate and assign to **daydatas** variable

Comment: i think everything will be fine if you remove the +1 after `this.daydatas.length`